# Chemipro Oxi Solution sucked in to beer during transfer

Tags: sanitizer

Will we have problems with this:
About 2-3oz of Sanitizing solution got sucked in to the 5 gallons of beer during transfer to the bottling bucket. It was Chemipro Oxi and was diluted to 1 Tablespoon per gallon of water. It is a non-rinse sanitizer that is made from Sodium 
Percarbonate. 
Thanks

Comment: It produces hydrogen peroxide, and then that becomes water + oxygen. Either the yeast in the bottles will multiply like mad, resulting in a lot of sediment, or the beer will become oxidated much faster than it should. I'm unable to tell which is more likely.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful and will see which happens.

Answer (score 5):

About **Sodium Percarbonate** (2 Na2CO3 + 3 H2O2) on wikipedia:

> Dissolved in water, it yields a mixture of hydrogen peroxide (which eventually decomposes to water and oxygen) and sodium carbonate ("soda ash")... The rate of decomposition increases with rising temperature (2 H2O2 → 2 H2O + O2).

So 3oz of this sanitizer would yield less than 2oz of water and 1oz of oxygen, and some sodium carbonate. All this dilluted in 5 gallons of beer.  I do not think it will make any significant changes to yeast or oxydation.  I do not know how long it will take for the hydrogen peroxide to decompose, but the higher temperature of bottle conditionning will help...

About **Sodium Carbonate** (soda ash) on wikipedia :

> It is also used as a water softener, since carbonate can precipitate the calcium and magnesium ions present in "hard" water.

Will the acidity of the beer be changed to the point of being vulnerable to infection, again I don't think such a small quantity will make a significant change.

Comment: If my chemistry is correct, dissolved Sodium Percarbonate will result in 3 parts Hydrogen Peroxide (~1.8oz) and 2 parts of Sodium Percarbonate(~1.2oz).  And the Hydrogen Peroxide will decompose into 2 parts water (~1.2oz) and 1 part oxygen(~0.6oz).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I also had a response from the distributor of the product who said it will break down in to oxygen and sodium carbonate. The amount of the sodium carbonate should be small at that dilution and won’t be a problem.